# Show that $\forall \epsilon >0 $ $\exists M >0 $ that $\forall x>M $ $\ln x < x^{\epsilon}$

Tags: calculus

I thought about defining a function $ g(x) =  \dfrac{1}{\epsilon}  x^{\epsilon} - \ln(x)   $ and show that it's larger than $0$. I saw that if I substitute
$1$, I get $\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}$ which is positive and so on. I also tried to derive the function and I got $g'(x) = x^{\epsilon -1} - \dfrac{1}{x}  $

I'm stuck. Can someone help me realize how to keep going?

**edit**: I need to show also that $\forall \epsilon >0 $ $\exists M >0 $  that $\forall x>M  $    $\ln x < x^{\epsilon}$ I thought about using what we proved just now by multiplying by $\epsilon$ both sides and get $    \epsilon \ln x < x^{\epsilon}$ define a new function $f(x) =     x^{\epsilon} - \epsilon \ln x$ and again if I derieve it I get $\epsilon x^{\epsilon -1} - \epsilon \dfrac{1}{x}$ get the $\epsilon$ out and get $\epsilon * (x^{\epsilon -1} - \dfrac{1}{x}) > 0 $.
The only problem with it I never use the $M$ can someone help me please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's very good progress!  You have $g'(x) = x^{\epsilon-1} - x^{-1}$ so to show this is positive (and thus $g(x)$ is increasing), show that $x^{\epsilon-1} > x^{-1}$ for $x >1$ and $0<\epsilon<1$.

Comment: Is there any specific theorem I should rely on?

Comment: I find it a little easier to show $1< x^{1-\epsilon} < x^1=x$ for those conditions then take reciprocals.  Which you could do by taking yet another derivative, since $1-\epsilon < 0$.

Comment: By the way I really liked the strategy you proposed show that the deritieve is positive which means the function is monotone increasing and the first point I subsitute was positive so it has to be true

Comment: @ElizabethS.Q.Goodman You mean $1 - \epsilon > 0 $ right?($0<\epsilon<1$)

Comment: Dat edit tho. This change completely the question.

Comment: Why? it's just the continuation of the original question

Answer (score 2):

If you are allowed to use :

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}x=0$$

then, given $\epsilon>0$, you can see that :

$$\forall x>0,\,\frac{\ln(x)}{x^\epsilon}=\frac 1\epsilon\frac{\ln(x^\epsilon)}{x^\epsilon}$$and since $\lim_{x\to+\infty}x^\epsilon=+\infty$, composition of limits shows that :

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^\epsilon}=0$$

Hence, for $x$ sufficiently large, we certainly have :

$$\frac{\ln(x)}{x^\epsilon}<1$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $c > 0$ and $\epsilon \in ]0,1[$. We start with the trivial inequality :
$$
\begin{align}
c &< c + \frac{1}{\epsilon} &\Longleftrightarrow \\
c & < \frac{1}{\epsilon}(1 + \epsilon c) & \overset{(*)}{\implies} \\
c & < \frac{1}{\epsilon} e^{\epsilon c} & \overset{(**)}{\implies} \\
\ln(x) &< \frac{1}{\epsilon} e^{\epsilon \ln(x)} = \frac{1}{\epsilon} x^{\epsilon}
\end{align}
$$
$(*)$ since $1+x \leq e^x, \forall x$.

$(**)$ Setting $c = \ln(x)$ for $x > 1$

Comment: More accurately : $$e^x \ge x+1 ~ \forall x$$ (consider $x=0$ )

Comment: @JaideepKhare Oups, you're right ! Corrected !

Comment: You've shown that  $\ln(x)<\frac1\varepsilon x^\varepsilon$. If $0<\varepsilon<1$, $\frac1\varepsilon>1$ and in turn $x^\varepsilon<\frac1\varepsilon x^\varepsilon$. I don't think you answered the question because the OP wanted to prove $\ln(x)<x^\varepsilon,\forall\varepsilon>0$ and sufficiently large $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative you could use L'Hôpital's rule to show
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{x^{\epsilon}} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^{-1}}{\epsilon x^{\epsilon-1}} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{\epsilon} x^{-\epsilon} = 0.$$
From this follows that from some point $x^\epsilon > \ln(x)$ otherwise the limit can't be $0$.

**Second approach:**
Use the $\exp$ function you know that $\exp$ is monoton so the inequality must hold if you add on both sides the exp function
\begin{align*}
\ln(x) < x^\epsilon \quad &\Leftrightarrow \quad \exp(\ln(x)) < \exp(x^\epsilon) \\ &\Leftrightarrow \quad 1 < \frac{\exp(x^\epsilon)}{x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{\epsilon n - 1}}{n!} =: f(x)
\end{align*}
So there is only left to show that $f(x) > 1$. For example use $x=\lceil\frac{1}{\epsilon}\rceil!$
 and show that $f$ is monoton from this point or at least still bigger than $1$. Showing that it is still bigger than $1$ should be easy.

Comment: Good point! unfortuneately I'm not allowed to use L'hopital yet :(

Comment: @user21312 I edited a second approach